# Is there any onAuthStateChanged equivalent for Firestore Data? i.e onDataFieldChanged

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im updating the App context when the user auth changes 
However, I need to change the context also when the user data on the firestore DB is changed

For instance:
The context in my app store the User Doc.
Each user document has a count field. When the user is finished to do some action the count is changed and I need to change the context to the updated user doc.

How can I do it?

Here is my Context file:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react'
import { auth, getUserDocument } from './firebase/firebase.utils'

export const UserContext = createContext({ user: null })

class UserProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    user: null,
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      const user = await getUserDocument(userAuth)
      this.setState({ user })
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={this.state.user}>
        {this.props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
export default UserProvider
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as 'accepted' if it has helped to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore offers you `Snapshot Listeners`, which are nothing but real-time event listeners fot your data.

In your case, you can simply add a `Snapshot Listener` on your document and you will get an event whenever the document changes. The snapshot gives you a `DocumentSnapshot` which is the updated document. [Read this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) for all the details.